# Bleichenbacher attack, binary search, formula for $s_i$

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, cryptanalysis, chosen-ciphertext-attack

Reading [an excellent article](http://www.dsi.unive.it/~focardi/RSA-padding-oracle/) explaining Bleichenbacher attack I came across the following statements under [the formula for $s_i$](http://www.dsi.unive.it/~focardi/RSA-padding-oracle/#eq5):

> if we pick $r ≥ 2(bs_{i-1} - 2B) / n$, we obtain
>
> $(2B + 2(bs_{i-1} - 2B)) / b = 2s_{i-1} ≤ s_i$

Can anyone explain to me how the previous equality is obtained? If we try to reproduce it, we'll obviously get:

$(2B + 2bs_{i-1} - 4B)/b=(2bs_{i-1} - 2B)/b=2s_{i-1} - 2B/b$

Why the authors conclude that the result behind is equal $2s_{i-1}$? Moreover, in the code later they use

```
r = ceil((b*si - B2)*2,n) # starting value for r
```

as a starting point for $r$...

Comment: Can you add more details? Specifically, what is the formula obtained before picking r?

Comment: @RitamBhaumik please use the links in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement in the [article](http://www.dsi.unive.it/~focardi/RSA-padding-oracle/) (I'm the author) is my personal explanation of Bleichenbacher's sentence "We use condition (1) because we want to divide the remaining interval in each iteration roughly in half." (see the [original paper](http://archiv.infsec.ethz.ch/education/fs08/secsem/Bleichenbacher98.pdf) at page 4).

But in fact, you are right, equality does not hold. I should have written $(2B + 2(bs_{i-1} - 2B)) / b \approx 2s_{i-1}$, which holds because as you noticed

$$ (2B + 2bs_{i-1} - 4B)/b=(2bs_{i-1} - 2B)/b=2s_{i-1} - 2B/b$$

but $2B/b < 1$ since $b > 2B$ ($b$ is inside the initial interval). Moreover, since we are working with integers $-2B/b$ is ininfluent most of the time. I think this is consistent with Bleichenbacher's "roughly in half", but in fact I've never asked him more detail about how he got that constraint :)

I'll update the article to reflect this discussion (btw I'm glad you liked it).

@Ritam: the attack is very efficient. We have optimised it and implemented on real devices.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation (and for the article)! Recently I implemented the attack and carried out several experiments with the constant $r$. The both ways actually work, but original $r = ceil((b*si - B2)*2,n)$ leads to less number of iterations. Anyway, thanks once again!

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I examined this for a while, and I'm pretty sure this is more of an oversight. They probably wanted to take $r\ge2bs_{i-1}-2B=2(bs_{i-1}-B)$. The same correction should go into the code. (Taking $r=2bs_{i-1}-2B$ is indeed too low a value and does not ensure the doubling of $s_i$ at every successive step, so your observation is correct.)

Comment: I removed previous comment, sorry for misleading you. I the original paper at https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/704790/filename/RR-7944.pdf , Page 6, Step 2c they use $r_i >= 2\frac{bs_{i-1} - 2B}{n}$, so is this a typo in the paper?

Comment: Looks like it, yes. It is best to mail them for a clarification. (The algorithm may work even for this starting value of r, but the guarantee of halving the search space does not seem to work.